# Sorting through JSON values?

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm a bit new to JSON, but here goes.  I'm using Google Charts, and am trying to figure out how to sort through a json_encode using javascript.

The format Google Charts expects is:

```
data.addRow([new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,0,3,0,0]);
```

My json_encode looks like:

```
[[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,0,3,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,0,1,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,1,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,2,0,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),42,0,0,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),20,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I'm basically coding it (php side) like this and returning $result through an AJAX call:

```
$test = json_encode($charts_count_history, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$result = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $test);
```

jsonData is the variable that stores the json_encode (string? array? Not sure what to call this).  My question is how could I sort through the jsonData and (for example) alert each value?  Maybe something like the below?

```
for(//Not sure what would go here)
{
alert(jsonData[0][0]);
}
```

I know I'm probably way off on how I should do this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Nothing to do with JSON (JSON is just *text*; it's JavaScript objects when dealing with the data *in* JavaScript). Anyway, the phrasing sought to find useful search results is ["custom sort in JavaScript"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+custom+sort) or similar.

Comment: Also, [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration) != [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). If a sort is desired, it is important to *define the sort rules*.

Comment: Nice call on the iteration versus sorting, terminology is one thing I definitely could improve on.

Answer (score 0):

When you encode data into JSON, it's type is a string.  Also be careful when you are structuring JSON:

```
[[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,0,3,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,0,1,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,0,1,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),0,2,0,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),42,0,0,0,0,0],[new Date(2008,0,1),20,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

should be

```
[new Date(), new Date(), ... , new Date()]
```

To loop through the above JSON in javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  alert(json[i]);
}
```

Comment: The JSON presented is fine. Although I don't know *what* the other values mean that is how it was encoded and returned by PHP. It might be advisable to return better looking JSON, but that's another issue ..